# Issues with coloring and formatting in svelte

Tags: svelte

My colors and formatting are all messed up in my svelte files, look at this, makes it really hard to work.

[image: screenshot]

[My svelte config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGvHO.png)

Im a beginner, so i dont know what to do.

```
{
  "[html]": {
  
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "svelte.svelte-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
  "svelte.enable-ts-plugin": true,
  "[svelte]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "svelte.svelte-vscode"
  },
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "files.associations": {
    "*.svelte": "html"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using VS Code? Have you installed the Svelte extension?

Comment: Yes, i have, and i still have issues :(

Comment: Show your various configuration files, `svelte.config.js`, `tsconfig.json` etc.

Comment: describe what you expect to see

Comment: I added my svelte config file, but i dont know where to check my other config files. And i excpect to see colors and proper formatting with prettier with this code, but vscode dosent recognize this code at all.

Comment: This might not be the only issue, but [the README for `svelte-vscode`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode) says *"If you added `"files.associations": {"*.svelte": "html" }` to your VSCode settings, remove it."* at the very top.